# Inconsistent results with concurrent function?

Tags: go, concurrency

I am trying to process lines from a file concurrently, but for some reason I appear to be getting inconsistent results.  A simplified version of my code is below:

```
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  semaphore := make(chan struct{}, 2)
  lengths:= []int{}

  for _, file := range(args[1:]){
    // Open the file and start reading it
    reader, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Problem reading input file:", file)
      fmt.Println("Error:", err)
      os.Exit(0)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)
    // Start streaming lines
    for scanner.Scan() {
      wg.Add(1)
      text := scanner.Text()
      semaphore <- struct{}{}
      go func(line string) {
          length := getInformation(line)
          lengths = append(lengths, length)
          <-semaphore
          wg.Done()
      }(text)
    }
  }
  wg.Wait()
  sort.Ints(lengths)
  fmt.Println("Lengths:", lengths)
```

The `getInformation` function is just returning the length of the line.  I then take that line and add it to an array.  The issue I'm having is that when I run this multiple times against the same file I get different number of items in my array.  I had assumed that since I was using a `waitGroup` that all lines would be processed every time and therefore the contents of `lengths` would be the same, but this does not appear to be the case.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In this case `wg.Wait()` shouldn't be right after the go routine?

Comment: @HamzaAnis - hrrm - it's not _right_ after the go routine right?  It's after the two `for` loops.  Does that change anything?

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem, you are getting different number of values here and order doesn't matter in your case. wg.Wait() should be after the go routine when  you would have needed ordered data in the array .

Comment: @HamzaAnis - you are right - that fixed it.  Can you explain why that works? I assumed `wg.Wait` was just telling everything to wait for all the go routines to finish and that it didn't really matter if it was after the call to the go routine or right before the function exited?

Comment: Yes you are right. It waits for all the go routines to finish and what was happening before is that while the routine was appending value in the slice the routine was ending and the `append` wasn't completing. that's why there were different length of slice.

Comment: Always run concurrent code under the race detector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `lengths = append(lengths, length)` is getting executed concurrently. This is not safe and will cause problems like missing entries from slice. You can fix this by wrapping the append calls in a mutex, or have the gorountines publish their results to a channel and have a single place that collects them up into a slice.